# Using a variable from one function in another function

Tags: jquery

I need to use the result of one of the objects returned by an Ajax call in another function.

My Ajax returns

```
0: "50037" 
1: "Company name"
2: "Bolton Suite"
3: "08-01-2020 08:00" 
4: "31-01-2020 16:00"
5: "2"
```

Function 1

```
success: function(data) {
  var result = $.parseJSON(data);
  if( result[5] == 2){
    GlobalRecordID = result[0]; //<--USE THIS VAR IN FUNCTION 2
    console.log("GLOBAL RECORDID", GlobalRecordID);
  }
}
```

When the form is submitted it runs a function which contains:

Function 2

```
$("#room_override_insert_promotion").submit(function(event){ 
var globalrecordid = GlobalRecordID; //<---------
```

I would like to be able to use 0: "50037" in function 2 which performs an edit of the underlying data table. So my question is, how do I dynamically populate the variable in function 2 with the content of GlobleRecordID.

Comment: What is the relation of function one to function two?

Comment: You may want to provide some more detail about exactly how you want this to work. There are a lot of possible ways to do something like this. Are you currently attempting to use a global variable and that isn't working? If so, note that the spelling of the global variable is different in the two places: `GlobleRecordID` in the first and `GlobalRecordID` in the second.

Comment: @Jack A. Hi. I have corrected the spelling errors, never spotted them. Yes I am trying to use the "GlobalRecordID" variable as a global variable. There is an underlying from and when date and time fields have been selected I have a function that checks to see if a record already exists for the same period. If a record does exist  "GlobalRecordID" get populated with the recordID. I then need to use that recordID in another function when the form is submitted. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you sure that your first ajax call is completing before the form is submitted? If so, I assume that the problem you're having is that the `GlobalRecordID` variable is empty in your second function? If so, it is probably because it is never declared in a global scope. One way to address this would be to reference it as `window.GlobalRecordID`. This will ensure that you are referencing the global variable in all cases.

Comment: @Jack A. Hi, I will give that a try. Many thanks for your help.